# How to get null value when summing a column has a null value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum

```
DECLARE  @tablo TABLE (oran INT,deger INT)
INSERT INTO @tablo
SELECT 10,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 10,20

SELECT oran*deger/100 FROM @tablo

SELECT SUM(oran*deger/100) FROM @tablo

SELECT NULL+2
```

When i use sum function it returns a value but if a column has a null value , i want it to return null.
How is it possible?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sum()` (as with the other aggregation functions) ignores `NULL`s when combining values from different rows.  You can do what you want with additional logic:

```
SELECT (case when count(*) = count(oran*deger)
             then SUM(oran*deger/100)
        end)
FROM @tablo;
```

The construct `count(*) = count(<whatever>)` is the shortest way I can think of to determine if a value is `NULL`.  The first part counts the number of rows in the group.  The second counts the number of non-NULL values.  If these are different, then there is a `NULL` value somewhere.